# Python - Помогите разобраться в проблеме связанной с умножением которая вместо знака "*" пишет "х" (speech_recognition)

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Я создаю голосовой калькулятор, однако у библиотеки speech_recognition есть такая особенность с умножением которая вместо знака "*" пишет "х" и я взялся её решать, но данная часть программы по каким то причинам работает через раз

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3 as pt
text = ""
l = text.split(" ")
r = sr.Recognizer()
def speech():
    global text
    global l
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as mic:
        print("Говорите...")
        try:
            audio = r.listen(mic, phrase_time_limit=7, timeout=7)
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='ru-RU')

        except(sr.WaitTimeoutError, sr.UnknownValueError):
            print("Я Вас не понял или не слышу...Скажите ещё раз...")
            speech()

        else:
            print(f"Вы сказали: {text}")
            count = 0
            l = text.split(" "
            for i in l:

#               ᐯ
                if i == "x":
                    l[count] = "*"
#               ᐱ

    return text
    return l


a = speech()
num = eval("".join([str(i) for i in l]))

print(f"Ответ: {num}")
engine = pt.init()
engine.say(num)
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: А почему бы просто в строке не заменить при помощи функции `replace()`?

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо тебе большое. Я раньше даже и не знал о такой функции